# Why does this code not specify which element of the array is accessed?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *fptr;

main()
{
    char fileLine[100];
    fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Summary.h", "r");

    if (fptr != 0){
        while (!feof(fptr)){
            fgets(fileLine, 100, fptr); // << not specified like fileLine[1] ?
            if (!feof(fptr)){
                puts(fileLine); // The same thing ? 
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\nErorr opening file.\n");
    }

     fclose(fptr);

     return 0;
}
```

The tremendous pain here, why the array elements are not specified, and how the array holds the lines?

Comment: `fileLine` is the start address of the array `char fileLine[100]`. From there each successive element can be accessed by adding `i` to the start where `i` is the index of the element in the array.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what part is unclear to you. For the working of `fgets`, see [a random Google result](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). However, it appears you are confused by the variable *name*: `fileLine` is *not* an array of 'lines'. Unfortunately, this is such a basic failure in understanding, it's hard to suggest where to look it up. Do you have a basic study book?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char fileLine[100];
> ```

This is not an array of lines, it's an array of characters. One `char` represents one character (or more precisely one byte). The declaration `char fileLine[100]` makes it an array of 100 characters. C doesn't have distinct types for strings and for arrays of characters: a string (such as the content of a line) is just an array of characters, with a null byte after the last character.

At each run through the loop, `fileLine` contains the line that is read by `fgets`. That string is printed out by `puts`. Each call to `fgets` overwrite the line that was previously stored in the string.

Note that since `fgets` retains the newline character that terminates each line, and `puts` adds a newline after printing the string, you will get double-spaced output. If a line is more than 99 characters long (strictly speaking, again, more than 99 bytes long), you'll get a line break after each block of 99 characters.

If you wanted to store all the lines, you'd need an array of strings, i.e. an array of arrays of characters.

```
char fileLines[42][100];
int i = 0;
while (!feof(fptr)) {
    fgets(fileLines[i], 100, fptr);
    ++i;
}
/* i-1 lines have been read, from fileLines[0] to fileLines[i-2] */
```

The way you're using `feof` is quite awkward there. `feof` tells you whether the last attempt to read reached the end of the file, not whether the next attempt to read would reach the end of the file. For example, here, after the last line has been read, `feof()` is false (because the program doesn't know yet that this is the last line, it has to attempt to read more); then `fgets` runs again, and returns `NULL` because it couldn't read anything. Nonetheless `i` is incremeneted; and after that `feof()` returns false which terminates the loop. Thus `i` ends up being one plus the number of lines read.

While you can fix this here by decrementing `i`, the way that actually works even in real-life programs — and that also makes more sense — is to test the result of `fgets`. You know that you've reached the end of the file because `fgets` is unable to read a line.

```
char fileLines[42][100];
int i = 0;
while (fgets(fileLines[i], 100, fptr))
    ++i;
}
/* i lines have been read, from fileLines[0] to fileLines[i-1] */
```

(This is a toy example, real-life code would need dynamic memory management and error checks for long lines, too many lines, and read errors.)

Comment: <Pedant Mode> Be careful when talking about bytes and the C/C++ language as a byte may not necessarily be 8 bits. </Pedant Mode>

Comment: @wildplasser Given that this is a toy example and I was trying to follow the structure of the code in the question, what is wrong? I should perhaps point out more strongly that the return value of `fgets` needs to be tested before doing anything with `fileLines[i]`, but apart from that?

Comment: What is wrong is that the last line will contain garbage (probably a copy of the previous last line), and that `i` will be one too high after the loop has finished.

Comment: @wildplasser I've shown how to go at it properly, i.e. test the return value of `fgets`. Nonetheless I don't understand where you're getting at with “the last line will contain garbage”. Or were you refering to `fileLines[i-1]`? That's not the last line, the last line is (indeed confusingly) `fileLines[i-2]`.

Comment: Yes, that looks better.

Answer (score 0):

The array of characters that is `fileLine` is treated as a string.